# Taking Out Max List from List of Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
L1 = {{500, {x->3, y-> 4, z -> 1}}, {110, {x->11, y->41, z -> 9}}, {750, {x-> 1, y->-1, z->0}}}
```

Is there a way to pull out the element with the largest element in the first position? So, in this case, we would have returned:

```
{750, {x-> 1, y->-1, z->0}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `MaximalBy[L1, First]` or  `Last@Sort@L1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html):

```
L1[[Ordering[L1[[All, 1]], -1]]]
```

> {{750, {x -> 1, y -> -1, z -> 0}}}

or a combination of `Part` and [`OrderingBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html):

```
L1[[OrderingBy[L1, First, -1]]]
```

> ```
> {{750, {x -> 1, y -> -1, z -> 0}}}
> ```

For large lists the first approach is faster.